# FullCalendar loaded with ajax doesn't build up the calender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin inside a page that i'm loading using ajax.
When the page is loaded all I get is the header buttons, but the calender itself doesn't show up until I click on one of the buttons (month/week/day).

This is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: { left: 'next,prev, today', center: 'title', right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'},
    isRTL: true,
    height: 540,
    events: {
        url: "../practice/AjaxJson",
        cache: true
    },
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'
});
```

If I put this code inside a function and call it using setTimeout that set to 1500ms it works.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: There is a refetch function in the docs. Use that instead of putting this whole calendar in a setTimeout loop.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/

Comment: That's better than what i'm doing, but is there no way to avoid using the setTimeout solution?

Comment: Unless you have triggers to probe manually to see if there are updates in the back-end, setTimeout is a solution. But I would prefer the manual one myself. At least you don't have to regenerate the whole calendar and call refresh with the "refetch"

Answer (score 0):

1. Just try to put your code after the dom is ready.
2. Use renderEvents (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/)
3. Make sure you are not loading the calendar on an hidden element.